# Java EE SDK for mac

Tags: java, sdk, osx-lion

After spending 3 solid days on this with nothing to be happy about. I'm being freaked out already. I'm a newly in java and just about getting it rolling in java ee...

Please, good people here. I am confused. I am looking for Java EE 6 SDK for mac os x lion 10.7.2 64bits.

I found on oracle's website java ee 6 sdk for unix and windows and no mac... spent tons of time on google and apple's website forums and support but found nothing pertaining to this.

Is it that mac does not need Java EE 6 SDK? or what? I already have netbeans installed and eclipse as well which I've been using during my early beginning stage in java SE.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac is the Unix, did you tried shell script they provided?

Comment: Thanks so much... The shell script worked real fine. God bless you!

Answer (score 1):

Java EE is an API, not a complete implementation ( that is provided by your application server where your code is deployed to).

Hence you just need the API jars.  This can, however, be avoided if you get the Netbeans+Glassfish bundle, and let Netbeans do the work by choosing an appropriate template when creating a new module.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot for your reply... I've had NetBeans 7.1.2 installed on my mac and it's got GlassFish Server 3.1.2 in it... I'm I good to go? or do I need do any other settings? Thanks once again...

Comment: Yes.  Just use the wizard for creating what you want to do.